# Graph Theory closest to be bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have two graphs [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBZyT.png)
I know it isn't bipartite, but I need to calculate which one is closest to being bipartite, it is related with bipartivity in network.
To define a measure of network bipartivity is based on the concept of
closed walks.
the bipartivity is defined of G as:
[bipartivity definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd99T.png)
is the sum of all closed walks of diferent lengths in the network starting and ending at each vertex of G.

My idea is to calculte te eigenvalues of each graph and do 
[bipartivity eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK7Zu.png)
I`m right?

thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you measure closeness to being bipartite?

Comment: I am unable to find any evidence that this textbook exists. I expect that the source of the question has some further details you've missed.

Comment: It's hard to say without details, in particular that ambiguity might be the intended part of the problem. Nevertheless, if I had to take a guess, it is a question about the minimal number of edges that you have to remove to make the graph bipartite.

Comment: You need to give us much more details, on the source you have what are the definitions? 

Bipartite graphs have many properties, symmetric eigenvalues, $C_3$ free, ...

Comment: Hi, can you help me with the explanation  about the minimal number of edges that you have to remove to make the graph bipartite. I think this question could be of this.

Comment: @dtldarek Hi, can you help me with the explanation about the minimal number of edges that you have to remove to make the graph bipartite. Thanks

Comment: @Fer Sorry, but currently I do not have any spare time. On the other hand, if you were to formulate your question clearer (edit, add details, what are your thoughts, etc.), I'm sure someone else will help you.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues thanks for your coment , T give  more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $|V(G)|=N$, The subgraph centralization measure can be defined as a weighted sum of
all closed-walks (CWs) of length $\ell$ in the network, $\mu_\ell$ , which is related to graph eigenvalues as follows :

$$ \langle SC \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_\ell \frac{\mu_\ell}{\ell !} = \sum_{j=1}^N e^{\lambda_j}$$

This can be expressed as the sum of two contributions, one coming from odd and the other
from even CWs:

$$ \langle SC \rangle  = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\cosh(\lambda_j) + \sinh(\lambda_j)\right) = \langle SC \rangle_{even} + \langle SC \rangle_{odd}$$

If $G$ is bipartite then it includes no odd closed walks, i.e. $\langle SC \rangle_{odd}=0$ and $$\langle SC \rangle  =\langle SC \rangle_{even} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N \cosh(\lambda_j)$$

Then indeed you can define a measure of the network bipartivity:
$$\beta(G) = \frac{\langle SC \rangle_{even}}{\langle SC \rangle} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N \cosh(\lambda_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{\lambda_j}}$$

You have, $\forall G$, $\beta(G)\leq 1$ with equality iif $G$ is bipartite. You also have a desired monotone property $\beta(G) \geq \beta(G+e)$

See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0504/0504729.pdf) by Ernesto Estrada1 and Juan A. Rodríguez-Velázquez for a full description, and the adequate proofs.

Comment: thanks I have read it yet, and i get the answer. If both graphs have B(G)< =1 the biggest one is closest to being bepartite its right?

Comment: Yes, they both have $\beta(\cdot) \leq 1$ by definition, and the closedt to $1$ (i.e.  bigger value) will be the closest to being biparitite for this definition

Comment: Thaks I get it!